# I can't see the Game status Window

Tags: chessmaster

I can't see Game Status Window. It looks like its position is beyond game window. How can I move it?

Screen: http://ifotos.pl/img/screen_hherxwe.jpg

Comment: Thanks for adding chessmaster-10 tag. I dont have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what you are seeing?  That might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah man I have had this exact problem! Sadly I don't remember how I fixed it but I would try the following:

1. Go to Preferences -> Layout -> Restore default.
2. If that doesn't work, change your screen resolution with Chessmaster running. It may force the app to reposition all its windows.
3. Or, look in the program directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Ubisoft\Chessmaster Grandmaster Edition` on my machine) and find an .ini file which stores the window positions, and manually edit it while Chessmaster is closed.

Comment: Option 1. is working :). It was so easy :P. Do you know how to fix those pink menus? I have Win7 64 bit

Comment: I am also on win7/64-bit, but ... pink menus? what do you mean? :P

Comment: oh i see in the screenshot... hmm i have no idea; they look fine on my machine :/